# how to develop application like LifeRay Control panel

Tags: liferay, icefaces

I want to develop an application like LifeRay control panel which has right navigation menu and a page that renders the clicked menu.

My question is how to develop at for example as one portlet or multi portlet taking into considaration (portlet communication)? and how to handle navigation inside portlet?

I'm using Icefaces(JSF) for portlet development and there is a section repeated for other pages(template)

Is there an example in liferay source for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just adjust a theme to have the navigation at the side as opposed to the default (at the top)? This way you'd be developing a plain portal application without any special magic - probably the most intuitive way to go.

Also, others will likely be able to quickly understand what you did and are able to add functionality.